# Strange behaviour of WPF project (class naming)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, class, naming

I got a strange error when tried to build my project `ExpertSystem` in solution `ExpertSystem`:

> Error 1   The type name 'App' does not
>   exist in the type
>   'ExpertSystem.ExpertSystem'   D:\Users\Kirill\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\ExpertSystem\ExpertSystem\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs    60  26  ExpertSystem

I didn't even knew that VS creates this file while building. So, I started search the problem in my last edits in code and found that problem is in my last class:

```
namespace ExpertSystem
{
    public class ExpertSystem
    {
    //...
    }
}
```

When name of class is changed to something different from `ExpertSystem`, project compiles without errors.

Can anyone explain, can I actually have classes in C# with the same name as namespace/project/solution? Or is this a some kind of VS/WPF bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone explain, can I actually have classes in C# with the same name as namespace/project/solution?

Yes, you can. It's part of the C# language.

Therefore the compiler can't figure out whether the code meant to look for the `ExpertSystem.ExpertSystem` namespace or the `ExpertSystem` class in the `ExpertSystem` namespace. (Well it can, but it got it wrong.)

Comment: The problem that i didn't started to use anywhere in code that class yet. Just defined it. So give me an advice, please, how can I actually solve such problem? For me will be better to leave that name of class.

Comment: @archer: Why can't you use a different name?

Comment: if renaming class is the only possible way, I can.

Comment: really, compiler thinks that in line `ExpertSystem.App app = new ExpertSystem.App();` of `Main()` `ExpertSystem` is the my class, not namespace. If i change to `App app = new App();` then works... But better to rename class. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

VS generates partial class for each XAML file (not during build, but during design), in order (for instance) to declare and fill the named components as class fields.

If you want to easily read the content of the designer generated App.g.css file (associated with the App.xaml and App.xaml.cs file), go to the App.xaml.cs file and perform a "Go to Definition" on the InitializeComponent() function call in the class constructor. I don't know what lurks in your, but I would expect that the designer generated something like this (maybe not this, but the issue will be the same):

```
var foo = (SystemExpert.App)(Application.Current)
```

Which should be understood as:

```
var foo = (global::SystemExpert.App)(Application.Current)
```

Now, if you create a SystemExpert class in your SystemExpert assembly namespace, and as the App class is declared in the SystemExpert namespace too, the compiler will understand that:

```
var foo = (global::SystemExpert.SystemExpert.App)(Application.Current)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         the current namespace
```

Naming a class exactly the same way as a namespace is bad practice: it can confuse the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [BoltClock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5436332/1430156) with a solution that will work while keeping the namespace and class names as they are:

The error is reported in a file named `App.g.cs`, which is generated by the compiler. Thus, fixing the issue in that file will not help, as the file will be overwritten with the error upon the next compilation (or rewritten once you have copied the code to another machine).

However, you *can* change the `App.xaml` file, from which `App.g.cs` is generated. The root element of the file will start with something like

```
<Application x:Class="ExpertSystem.App"
```

In there, the namespace `ExpertSystem` is supposed to be found, but with the class having the same name, the compiler assumes that `App` is a member or a nested type in your class `ExpertSystem.ExpertSystem`.

By pondering about this, you will realize that the compiler first tries to evaluate the value of the `x:Class` attribute relatively to the `ExpertSystem` namespace for some reason. This behaviour is responsible for your problem, but as we now know the specifics of the behaviour, we can write the code accordingly - with an identifier that is qualified relatively to the namespace `ExpertSystem`:

```
<Application x:Class="App"
```

After this change, it should compile fine, even if both the namespace and the class are named `ExpertSystem`.